# Gzip Compression of JSON in Spring RestController+Glassfish 4.1

Tags: json, spring, rest, glassfish-4.1

In stackoverflow, I found similar questions however answers didn't work for me.

I enabled gzip and minimum length in admin console and restarted the server.When I send request from Chrome to the corresponding url, the result is in JSON format. What should I do?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/get/user", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")  
 public User getUser( @RequestParam(value="id") Long id)  
 {  
     return getUser(id);
 }
```